# What city gives the most cash?

Tags: infectonator-2

What city gives the most repeatable cash (excluding challenges) and is relative easy to not destroy, for when you want to farm cash for getting all research done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Secret Base 2 in Russia can wield 10-13k per run as well, so it's nice to do while the strength of your zombies falls within the window of being able to beat the level, but not totally obliterating it within 35-seconds.

Also, if you haven't beaten that specific level yet, you could probably toss in a grenade each run as insurance to not complete the "No Support" challenge.

Answer (score 3):

Buenos Aires is also one to look out for.

One of the challenges is to use the Canister Bomb so avoid using them to keep the city, also it's pretty tight spaced with 200 people so it's very easy to get at least 11k gold a pop :)

Answer (score 2):

Best would be Rio de Janeiro. About 11k per run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to [Infectonator 2](http://www.unblockedgamesroom.com/infectonator-2) then Buenos Aires would be the best choice for you, you usually get 11-13k.

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to StackExchange!  Your answer doesn't seem to be any improvement over Leo's answer.  Please consider contributing additional information or edit the existing answer instead.

Comment: To add to @Nelson s comment, we do not condone duplicate answers. If you wish to confirm Leo's answer, simply click the up arrow above its score, and up-vote it. We do not want users scrolling through a list of identical answers, and the voting system works better in bringing more reliable answers to the top.

Answer (score -2):

darwin is a easy one if you have pent people on+

Comment: You may wish to revisit this, due to not making sense as is.